# How to automatically close the new popup window in Javascript and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a main window (`main.php`) on which there is a link, clicking on which opens a new popup window (`newpopup.php`).

```
<a href="" onclick="openNewPopUpWindow()">Open New Popup Window</a>

function openNewPopUpWindow() 
{   
    window.open("newpopup.php", "_blank", "height=340, width=600, status=yes, toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=no, addressbar=no, top=250, left=500"); 
}
```

Now, in this `newpopup.php`, I am updating some records by firing `MYSQL` query. My requirement is that, as soon as the query is fired and database is updated, this window should get automatically closed and my parent window `main.php` should get refreshed.

Following is the simple code snippet for `newpopup.php` file:

```
<?php
$query="UPDATE users SET isActive = 1";
$mydb->dbnonquery($con, $query);
header("Location:http://localhost/myProject/main.php");
?>
```

But, this code is not working. After the query is fired successfully, window is not getting closed and main window is also not getting refreshed.

**Update:**

I am able to close my newpopup.php window by ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "process_newpopup.php",
data: {"param1" : myparameter},
success: function (data) 
{
    window.close(); 
}
});
```

I have taken my PHP logic to update database in the `process_newpopup.php` file. When this logic is executed, `window.close()` method is executed. So, half of the problem is resolved. Now only problem persisting is how should I refresh my main page (`main.php`)?

**Update 2:**

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "process_newpopup.php",
data: {"param1" : myparameter},
success: function (data) 
{
  window.opener.location.reload();    
  window.close(); 
}
});
```

Adding `window.opener.location.reload();` solved my second part of problem that is to refresh the parent window.

Comment: Have you tried using [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) request ?

Comment: $mydb->dbnonquery($con, $query); is my own line for updating the database. So, please don't bother about it as its working fine.

Comment: @tektiv - no, and I have no clue how will it get automatically closed even if that window is opened by AJAX request.

Comment: As PHP runs on the **server** and not in the browser, it's impossible to close a popup using PHP. But you can generate markup in PHP that closes the popup in JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this string header("Location:http://localhost/myProject/main.php");

it's redirect header, so if you didn't output anything before it

for example: some text, or php notices, content of newpopup.php will be replaced by main.php

you have to change newpopup.php

```
<?php
   $query="UPDATE users SET isActive = 1";
  // where is $mydb variable defined?
  $mydb->dbnonquery($con, $query);
?>

<script>
   // works on chrome, will reload opener window main.php
   // don't forget this will be work only on same domain (read about cors)
   window.opener.location.reload();
   // will close current window, but not refreshes parent
   window.close();
</script>
```

Comment: window.opener.location.reload(); worked :). I just called it in my AJAX request before window.close(). Thanks a lot.

Comment: it's not ajax way, when you opening popups)

Answer (score 0):

You could refresh the popup as last action but with a query parameter `&close=yes`.

In the PHP script which creates the popup, print inside the HEAD section:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["close"])) {
    $close = $_REQUEST["close"];
} else {
    $close = "";
}
if ($close == "yes") {
    print "<script>window.opener.location.reload(); window.close();</script>";
}
```

When the popup reloads it refreshes the calling page (optional) and closes the new popup.